# Finding centriod given circumcenter, orthocenter, and direction from the origin.

Tags: geometry

I pose this problem to figure complete a answer on a problem with I have gotten far in but I am stuck here. I don't want to delete my answer because of how far I gotten anyways here is the issue I'm facing:

Let $A$ be the centroid of a triangle whose orthocentre and circumcentre are $(2,4)$ and $(\frac72,\frac52)$, respectively. Given that the centroid forms a 45-45-90 right triangle with the x-axis and origin find the distance of point $A$ from the origin.

My idea Let us call $A=(x_0,y_0)$ then $A$ is isosceles so $A=(x_0,x_0)$ $d=\sqrt{x_0^2+x_0^2}=\sqrt{2} |x_0|$

Then from the given information $x_0=2$?

Correct or no?

To be more clear the right triangle formed by the $x$ axis, origin, and point $a$ looks like this:

Please exuse my sucky drawing $b$ is the origin and $a$ is $A$, pretend it is 45-45-90:

[image]

Comment: You need to know about the Euler Line: the centroid lies on the line segment joining the orthocentre to the circumcentre and is 2/3 of the way along, so at $(3,\frac{7}{2})$.

Comment: Hmm, so using the two points I come up with a $line$ then use the fact that $A=(x_0,y_0)=(x_0,x_0)$ to come up with the coordinates of $x_0$ and ultimately $d$?

Comment: By Euler's theorem $H-O=3(G-O)$, hence $$ G = \frac{1}{3}(H+2O).$$

Comment: Not really sure what is H-O or G-0. I got d=3 using what Almagest. Is that supported by your solution?